# Modus in the reykjavik open 2015

Tags: tournament

- Is it correct that the reykjavik open 2015 is a KO tournament ?
- If the game is a draw, does black achieve the next round ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, according to the [tournament page](http://www.reykjavikopen.com/info/tournament-rules/); it is a Swiss.

Comment: In the chessgames.com-site, the numbers of games from the players shown go from 1 to 3. This is, why I drew the conclusion that it is a KO-tournament. Thanks.